# What is meant by the numbers before the "Z" in "2019-10-24T00:00:00.181Z"

Tags: time, utc, iso, iso8601

```
2019-10-24T00:00:00.181Z
```

What is meant by the `181Z` here? I have seen `Z` stands for Zulu time. But what is with the other three digits "181" here? 
So is this an ISO8601 formatted time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of research

Comment: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `181` are the milliseconds. For example, JavaScript's [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method returns an ISO date string in this format.

Comment: Thank you very much d4nyll. I was thinking it is something related to timezone. Now I understood this well.